# python - sorting dictionary by length of values and alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
db = {'Carl': [('Intel', 30, 40), ('Dell', 20, 50), ('Intel', -10, 60), ('Apple', 20, 55)], 'Barb': [('Intel', 20, 40), ('Intel', -10, 45), ('IBM', 40, 30), ('Intel', -10, 35)], 'Alan': [('Intel', 20, 10), ('Dell', 10, 50), ('Apple', 80, 80), ('Dell', -10, 55)], 'Dawn': [('Apple', 40, 80), ('Apple', 40, 85), ('Apple', -40, 90)]}
```

and a function that takes a dict argument:

```
def frequent_traders(db : {str: [(str,int,int)]}) -> [str]:
    client_names = list()

    for k in sorted(db, key = lambda k:len(db[k]), reverse = True):
        client_names.append(k)

    return client_names
```

I want to return a list of keys in decreasing order based on the length of their values. I've done so in the function above, but I'm not sure how to return them in increasing alphabetical order if they have the same length of values.

Comment: Check about any tutorial on sorting in Python; you need to use alphabetical order as a secondary key.

Comment: @pissall - but `list` is ordered, and that is what he is constructing. In fact, that's the whole point of `frequent_traders` :  to convert an unordered `dict` into an ordered `list`.

Comment: @pissall i've already sorted the keys by length in my function and returned them in a list. Some of the keys have the same length and i want to order them alphabetically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(db, key = lambda k: (-len(db[k]), k))
```